# Are there other ways to convert a bitmap for upload to a php server without using the Base64 encoding/decoding?

Tags: php, android, bitmap, base64

I want to transfer a bitmap, convert to jpeg (which I can do) and post it via http to a php server.  After reviewing the php script on the server, it does not use base64 endcoding/decoding at all.  I've seen and used the Base64 encoding/decoding, as listed below, but the server's api isn't taking it. I also doubt that at this time I can get the api on the php server updated. The api on the server currently support the 32bit iPhones, in case that provides a clue.

Also are there any concerns with the image itself?

I haven't seen any decoding/encoding in the php code just that standard 'move_uploaded_file' and I'm not a php programmer.

This doesn't work for the particular php server.

```
public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
    Bitmap immage = image;

    Integer quality = 80;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    immage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return imageEncoded;

}

public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {


    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}
```

I also tried a Base32 encoder/decoder.

```
public static String encodeToBase32(Bitmap image) {
    Bitmap immage = image;

    Integer quality = 90;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    immage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base32.encode(b);
    return imageEncoded;

}
```

and also tried just a straight byte array changing the 2nd to last line above to

```
String imageEncoded = String.valueOf(b);
```

Are there any other ways to send the image?

Comment: Why you not convert bmp to jpg file and post to PHP as multipart form data

Comment: Indeed. Be glad the script does not accept base64 encoded images. That would be 30% more bytes to transfer. Code for posting bytes/files has been posted on this site very often.

Comment: Anim - I'm looking a multipart forms now, as that is what the php server is using, just found out and hour ago.  Looking for a version where I don't have to go back too far.  I don't want to have multiple version of httpConnections or httpClients.  Thanks.  Suggestions?

Comment: Amin - Followed your suggestion, post it as an answer so I can give you credit.